# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME Angular 7

Tags: angular

I have a problem to render an image out of the Angular project.  Have this error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

This is my code:

```html
<div class="op-product-thumb-holder" *ngFor="let item of editImage; let indexImage = index">
        <img class="image-holder"   src="{{item.image_path}}"  />
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue, make sure that the address you are providing in the image source attribute is appended with "http://".

your URL must be somewhat like this:

"http://localhost:3000/assets/images/whatever.png"

The problematic part actually was that when you write it in the browser's URL, without http://, it automatically appends it without letting us know but this isn't the case with Angular.

Comment: Now I set like this and I have same problem :
 `<div class="op-product-thumb-holder" *ngFor="let item of editImage; let indexImage = index">
        <img class="image-holder"   src="http://localhost:3000/assets/slide-1.jpg"  />`

Comment: if you are manually setting you need it, what i meant was make sure you are not loading https://https you can check it in the network tab